# Selenium recursive content testing?

Tags: selenium

Assume a web-site has following structure

```
 Link1 -> Huge Sublinks (Example Link11, Link12,...) -> Link 11 -> Huge Sub 
 Links (Example Link 111, Link 112..... ) -> Link 111 -> Huge Sub Links 
 (Example Link 1111, Link 1112.....)

 Link2 -> Huge Sublinks (Example Link21, Link22,...) -> Link 21 -> Huge Sub 
 Links (Example Link 211, Link 212..... ) -> Link 211 -> Huge Sub Links 
 (Example Link 2111, Link 2112.....)
```

similarly Link3, Link4

Now i need to traverse each link Link1, Link2, Link3, Link4 to extract few content on the last page where there is not subsequent links exist recursively.

But currently recursively is not working and it throws

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

as the current page is different and unable to retain the old element info and the page has been moved to a new page, it throws error.

What is the best way to search for a content recursively ???

Sample Code Snippet:

```
public static void visitChildPages(String webSite) {
    driver.get(webSite);
    List<WebElement> liElements =      
    driver.findElementsByClassName("company");
    for(WebElement liElement : liElements) {
        List<WebElement> childs = liElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
        for(WebElement childEl : childs) {
          link = childEl.getAttribute("href");
          if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(link) && link.contains("http")) {
                visitChildPages(link);
           } else { 
               WebElement todaysClimate = childEl.findElement(By.id("ceoName"));
            }
         }
     }
   }
```

Comment: instead of using selenium..have a look at web crawlers to extract data

Comment: You really don't want to implement a web crawler using an interactive protocol like WebDriver. It's expensive to parallelise and your throughput will be orders of magnitude slower than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your case a pattern like [Loadable component](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/selenium-webdriver-practical/9781782168850/ch09s04.html) could be only a temp solution. It keeps page navigation logic across all Page objects.

If you are after just some page  content you can navigate directly to the page URL. But yet again this is a partial solution.

> way to search for a content recursively

is maybe a combination of URL traversal tool like [Xenu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu%27s_Link_Sleuth) and a parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). You can export the found and visited links by the first one and pass the collection to the second, which will validate your exact  page among all others.

Comment: Keeping the links and iterating the map it little bit cumbersome.

Comment: If the link map doesn't change often, I guess  the LoadableComponent is a good option then. Are you willing to consider URL navigation?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way and it works is

1. Create hash maps with navigation with current url
2. Finally iterate the hash map and get the values.

We need to create hashmap with url whenever the url changes.

Assume if we have to navigate 10 urls from the first page, we will have 10 hashmaps.

It works well but need to try the above softwares if required.